# cm12 build for one plus failed

Tags: android, build, makefile, cyanogenmod, oneplusone

I am trying to build cm12 for One Plus. But I get the following error and the build process stops. I checked [CM12 build failed for oneplus one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057146/cm12-build-failed-for-oneplus-one) also. Can anyone please help? I used
1). build/envsetup.sh
2)brunch bacon

```
 make[1]: Entering directory    '/home/xyz/Codes/CM12/kernel/oneplus/msm8974'
make: *** No rule to make target '/home/xyz/Codes/CM12/out/host/linux-x86/bin/dtbToolCM', needed by '/home/xyz/Codes/CM12/out/target/product/bacon/dt.img'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer from XDA. Need to get device/qcom/common by cloning https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_qcom_common .

This link helped me

[Link To XDA answer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/chef-central/android/guide-android-rom-development-t2814763/page29)