# Compiling Android from source, "no rule to make target" tbToolCM error

Tags: android

I'm trying to help out a friend of mine by compiling a ROM for the Samsung Galaxy Grand 2 (ms013g).

```
make: *** No rule to make target
'/home/quiche/cmsource/out/host/linux-x86/bin/dtbToolCM' needed by
'/home/quic/out/target/product/ms013g/dt.img '.
```

I keep getting this error i cannot fix, i tried the fix described here: [CM12 build failed for oneplus one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057146/cm12-build-failed-for-oneplus-one)
and i also made sure `android_device_qcom_common` is in my `local_manifest.xml`.
Somewere else, someone suggested changing `dtbToolCM` to `dtbTool`, which i tried to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like You need to add suitable kernel project to your local manifest

Downloading of android_kernel_samsung_klte project helped to me (I was building device_samsung_klte)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to add below to your Device.mk

`BOARD_KERNEL_SEPARATED_DT :=true`

Please see [Android.mk for dtbtool](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_qcom_common/blob/cm-12.1/dtbtool/Android.mk).

Thank you.